# Target platforms iOS and Android are missing in C++Builder 11

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-11-alexandria

I have installed C++Builder 11 Professional and the latest patches, but I am not seeing Target Platforms for iOS or Android. I have made sure that installation included these platforms, attached devices for iOS and Android. Nothing.

I tried a project developed with CB 10.4.2 and a new project for CB 11.0 (created with the wizard). This installation is on Windows 11 (with updates). I reported this on QP (RSP-36579), but no joy.

Has anyone made this work?

Comment: Are the platforms present and enabled in your project's `.cbproj` file?

Comment: Yes in the project developed with CB 10.4.2, no in the project created with CB 11 project wizard. The project created by CB 10.4.2 includes:
<Project ... >
    <PropertyGroup>
         ...
        <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)'==''">iOSDevice64</Platform>
        <TargetedPlatforms>1041</TargetedPlatforms>

The project created with CB 11 wizard includes
<Project ... >
    <PropertyGroup>
         ...
        <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)'==''">Win32</Platform>
        <TargetedPlatforms>3</TargetedPlatforms>

Comment: `1041` is Win32+Android+iOSDevice64, `3` is Win32+Win64. But, I was thinking more of the `<Platforms>` node instead.  Does it have iOS and Android present and set to `True`?

Comment: Sorry. The CB 10.4.2 project has the <Platforms> node which contains <Android> and <iOSDevice64> nodes present and set to True.

The CB 11 project has the <Platforms> node which contains <Android> and <iOSDevice64> nodes present and set to False! That looks fishy doesn't it?

Comment: Well, then try setting them to True and reload the project, does that fix the problem?

Comment: I did this with the CB 11 created project but no joy. The CB 10.4.2 project also doesn't work. Good suggestion though!

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a licensing issue. Embarcadero tech support advised me to delete the license file (*.slip & .cgb_license) at C:\ProgramData\Embarcadero\ from my computer, start C++ Builder and re-register my serial number. This seems to create corrected license files which permit support for developing apps for mobile targets.

I don't know why this happened but I'm delighted to have the issue resolved. If someone else runs into this, these instructions should help!

Answer (score 0):

I "lost" my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy A40), i.e. Rad Studio 10.4.2 stopped showing it in under the "Target Platforms / Android 32 bit" node. The way I reconnected it was as follows :

With Rad Studio open and project loaded :

- Unplug phone from laptop
- On the phone, go into Settings \ Developer Options
- Scroll down to "USB Debugging" and switch it off.
- Click on "Revoke USB Debugging Authorisations", then click "Ok"
- Turn USB Debugging back on
- Come out of settings
- Reconnect the phone, then click on "Allow USB Debugging"

At last I can now develop and debug my apps again.